# issues Running GPUGalaxySim.java using aparapi jar in Oracle Java Development Kit on Windows

Tags: java, cmd, gpu, aparapi

I've written a program that does some calculations to display a galaxy.I want to run it within jdk command prompt but i get this error.Compiling the program with aparapi works fine.When i try to run it,i get this:
[image]

Btw after i compile it I get many files which are these:

[image]

As u can see,the api library is in a different folder.

The commands I write are those two:

1)javac -g -cp ..\dist_windows_x86_64\aparapi.jar;. GPUGalaxySim.java

2)java -cp ..\dist_windows_x86_64\aparapi.jar;. -Djava.library.path=..\dist_windows_x86_64 GPUGalaxySim

Of course the commands are written after i go to the folder that contains the files u can see in the picture,called dist_x86_64.

Please help

Comment: I guess the class is located in a dedicated package (and thus, it should also be contained in a folder that has the same name as the package). For a simple test, you may try removing the line `package gpugalaxysim;` from the Java file.

Comment: Deleting the package name didnt work.

Comment: The error message in the first image seems to be a different one than before (before it said something about a wrong class name..!?). Do you have an OpenCL implementation? That is, is the `OpenCL.dll` in your `PATH`?

Comment: I dont have any opencl.dll

Comment: The link for the aparapi library is this https://github.com/aparapi/aparapi/releases/download/1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/dist_windows_x86_64.zip

Comment: Do you have an NVIDIA or an AMD card? Did you install a recent driver? Does your `C:\windows\system32` directory contain an `OpenCL.dll`?